# Default size of text column in Rails (PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, orm

If I have this in a migration:

```
t.text :body
```

How much text can I fit in `:body`? (I'm using PostgreSQL if that's relevant)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

straight from [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html)

```
text    variable unlimited length
```

Meaning you can put any length of string in a text column when using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5):

I believe that it stores it in a [text column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/datatype-character.html), which is toted as being, "variable unlimited length".