# PostgreSQL DATALINK type in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to use DATALINK type (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/DATALINK) in Rails 3.2, but it is not supported.

With this migration file:

```
def up
  change_column :images, :image_url, :datalink
  change_column :images, :source_url, :datalink
end
```

This shows up during the migration:

`PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "datalink" does not exist`

I've tried using https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext/tree/1-0-stable but got the same output.
Any idea?
Alternatively, how can I safely store an URL without using `:string`, because it is converted to `type character varying(255)`, which is a bit limited:

`PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)`

And using `:text` does not feel like, the best way :P

Comment: Since you're using Postgres, `text` is fine. You can also pass a longer `limit` option to `string` if you prefer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have a `datalink` type.

The wiki page you linked to is a design document. I've added some text to make that clear:

> This is a design document describing planning for a feature that may not yet exist in PostgreSQL. See the official documentation for your version to get information on available features.

Simply [use the PostgreSQL `text` datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332402/default-size-of-text-column-in-rails-postgresql) or tell rails to leave the length unlimited - PostgreSQL doesn't require that `varchar` has a length limit, it's just Rails's stupid default that creates that limit.

Comment: ohhhh, thank you for the enlightenment! (btw, there's a typo in "yoir")